# What [k] is in python sorting with lambda function?

Tags: python, sorting, generic-lambda

I don't understand the lambda k function, and especially, what is the last [k] in this line of code?

```
sorting_permutation = sorted(range(len(prediction_test[0:m_test])), key=lambda k: prediction_test[0:m_test][k])
```

I am so sorry for my English.

Comment: It's indexing the `k`th element in `prediction_test[0:m_test]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We should analyse the whole function. You want to sort `range(len(prediction_test[0:m_test]))` . Assuming `m_test` isn't greater than `len(prediction_test)` , this should give a list containing numbers from `0` to `m_test-1` .

Key parameter of sorting function defines the function that the list is accordingly sorted.  `k` values are the elements of the list that you want to sort. In your code, `k` will take values `0,1,2...,m_test-1` under the assumption. With `prediction_test[0:m_test][k]`  you first take a slice of prediction_test from index `0` to index `m_test`, then you take the element at `k`th index.

In a nutshell,
`key=lambda k: prediction_test[0:m_test][k]` means that you will sort your list according to results of  `prediction_test[0:m_test][k]`  where k will take values of your elements in the list. Your code is probably used for sorting the indices of a list according to values that they store.

Comment: Thank you so much, you solve my wrong idea.